# How to solve this similar triangle question?

Tags: trigonometry

Isosceles triangle ABC satisfies: $|AB|=|AC|=5$, and $\angle BAC>60$ degrees. The length of the perimeter of this triangle is expressed with a whole number. How many triangles of that kind are there?

```
   A. 1
   B. 2
   C. 3
   D. 4
   E. 5
```

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

$$\cos\angle BAC=\frac{AB^2+AC^2-BC^2}{2 AB\cdot AC}$$

and as $\displaystyle\angle BAC>60^\circ,\cos\angle BAC<\frac12$

Establish that $|BC|>5$

Now use  [Sum of Two Sides of Triangle Greater than Third Side](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Sum_of_Two_Sides_of_Triangle_Greater_than_Third_Side)

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

By simple trigonometry, the third side $BC$ has length $2\times 5 \times \sin(\frac{1}{2}\angle BAC)$, which is $10 \times \sin(\frac{1}{2}\angle BAC)$.

As $\angle BAC$ is greater than $60^\circ$, what value will length $|BC|$ exceed?

Now, what do you think length $|BC|$ should be less than? Hint: the Triangle Inequality.

Once you have the bounds for length $|BC|$, how many integer values lie in these bounds?

Here is a picture to help explain things:-

[image: Finding length BC]

You can use the Sine Rule to calculate $|BC|$ - although it's a bit more involved, I will go through it.
We have

$\large \frac{|BC|}{\sin \angle BAC}=\frac{5}{\sin \angle CBA}$

Now, as ABC is an isosceles triangle,  $\angle CBA= 0.5\times(180^{\circ}-\angle BAC)= 90^{\circ}-\frac{1}{2}\angle BAC$

So, we have

$\large \frac{|BC|}{\sin \angle BAC}=\frac{5}{\sin (90^{\circ}-\frac{1}{2}\angle BAC)}=\frac{5}{\cos \frac{1}{2}\angle BAC}$

Using the double angle formula, $\sin \angle BAC=2sin(\frac{1}{2}\angle BAC)cos(\frac{1}{2}\angle BAC)$, resulting in

$\large \frac{|BC|}{2sin(\frac{1}{2}\angle BAC)cos(\frac{1}{2}\angle BAC)}=\frac{5}{\cos \frac{1}{2}\angle BAC}$

leading to

$|BC|=2\times 5 \times \sin(\frac{1}{2}\angle BAC)$

Comment: we can draw a straight line (h) to bisect ∠BAC, such that we draw a right angled triangle within the triangle BAC. I am not clear how you get the height h, the line that bisects the ∠BAC. And who do you get the following: 2×5×sin(12∠BAC). I have tried cos rule and sine rule, but was not able to find length BC.

Comment: It seems that we have to guess a lot by trial and error. I do not see much logic.

Comment: Please see figure I have added to my answer for $2\times5\times sin(\frac{1}{2}\angle BAC)$

Comment: Thanks for the elaboration. The key aspect of this question is that the perimeter of the triangle is a whole number. Do we need to keep on plugging values for ∠BAC, to find the length of |BC|, which should be a whole number. For instance, if we take a random angle greater than 60 degrees, assuming ∠BAC=120. Plugging this back to |BC|=2×5×sin(1/2∠BAC), we get |BC|=2×5×sin(1/2. (120))= 8.66; this value for |BC|=8.66 does not work as it is not a whole number. Do we need to keep on guessing values for the angle? Or is there another method to reach the solution. Thanks

Comment: The main thing to realise is that the condition of $\angle BAC$ being greater than $60^\circ$ is that it sets a value that the length $|BC|$ must exceed, which will be $5$. Using the triangle inequality, we have a value for which length $|BC|$ must be less than (this is when $\angle BAC$ approaches its maximum value of $180^\circ$). So we have a range of values that $\angle BAC$ can take. All you need to do is find integer values of $|BC|$ that satisfy these limits - you do not have to do a search through all possible values of the angle.